# Como obtener el id de un view que acabo de agregar a un layout..?(Android)

Tags: android

Despues de:

```
    TextView iv = new TextView(this);
    iv.setText("Letrasletras");
    //Este es el ID
    int id=100+1;
    //Aqui se asigna el ID
    iv.setId(id);

    ElLayout.addView(iv);
```

Exactamente de que manera puedo usar el "findViewById" (o el equivalente) con ese nuevo elemento..?

Si tienen otra sugerencia , es bienvenida , el objetivo es crear un elemento(del tipo "View") y poder interactuar con el mismo.

Gracias =D

Por poner un ejemplo mas sencillo

Supongamos que necesitas hacer esto:

```
private TextView lblMilisegundos;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    lblMilisegundos = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblMilisegundos);
```

}

Pero , "private TextView lblMilisegundos"(o el TextView en el xml) , aun no ha sido escrito , va a "existir" , en el momento en el que escribas esto:

```
 ElLayout.addView(iv);
```

Comment: No se entiende bien para qué quieres usar  `findViewById` ahí  ¿? Para lo único que serviría sería para crear una elemento duplicado: `TextView tvDuplicado (TextView) ElLayout.findViewById (id);` ¿Acaso eso es lo que quieres, tener otra referencia del `TextView` que acabas de agregar?

Comment: El codigo crea elementos "View"(text , image , etc)  , pero despues de ser creados necesito poder "utilizarlos" , para que yo pueda dirigir los distintos metodos(setText , setImageresource , etc) , necesito obtener el ID para aplicar los respectivos metodos , como hago eso..?

Comment: Pero el id ya lo tienes, es la variable `id` que has seteado más arriba: `iv.setId(id);`, o sea, el id en el caso de tu ejemplo sería `101`. Pero realmente, no entiendo qué quieres hacer ni para qué. Ten cuidado al manejar las vistas de forma indiscriminada, a veces es un manejo costoso que tiene su precio a nivel de rendimiento. ¿Por qué no tienes elementos diferenciados en archivos XML y los referencias según los vayas necesitando? O bien ¿lo que necesitas no será más bien un `RecyclerView` o un `CardView` o algo así?

Comment: Si , tengo el id  , pero para que yo pueda ejecutar metodos necesito establecer un nuevo objeto (textView o Imageview) y despues decirle cual objeto de el xml es,  el cual antes de  "ElLayout.addView(iv)" , no existia , tal cual como si todo fuese "setteado" desde el Oncreate que se crea por defecto  , pero , considera que dicho objeto no existia , entonces , usar text=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.idtext); , no aplica para android , hasta antes de crear el view en el xml , no devuelve "null" y ya(como en javascript) , marca error y no se puede ejecutar la app. =/

Comment: me explique mal en esta parte " necesito obtener el ID para aplicar los respectivos metodos"(de el 2do comentario), disculpa.

Comment: Yo sigo sin entender. Ya tú tienes el id del elemento en la variable `id`... Si quieres crear una referencia de ese elemento lo haces así: `TextView tvDuplicado (TextView) ElLayout.findViewById (id);` y luego lo usas. Por ejemplo: `tvDuplicado.setText("Prueba");`

Comment: Ok , debe ser asi?  :

TextView iv = new TextView(this);
iv.setText("Letrasletras");
int idd=100+1;
iv.setId(idd);

rl.addView(iv, params);

TextView iv_tag = new TextView(this);

iv_tag=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.101);

-------      ---------    -------------------

Si lo hago asi , android me marca error en:

iv_tag=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.101);

En javascript ,  iv_tag devolveria null y  fin de la historia , en android me marca error y no puedo ejecutar   =/   (puse una actualizacion  , si puedes , revisala gracias por tu tiempo   =)      )

Comment: Es que si tú quieres obtener el `TextView` en otra parte, primero tienes que crear una referencia al layout donde lo has creado, y luego inflar ese layout en el actual. Entonces podrás acceder al `TextView`.  Lo que no entiendo es por qué, si tú tienes ya un `TextView` en ese contexto ¿para qué quieres otro? A mi me da la impresión de que lo que necesitas realmente es algo como un `RecyclerView` o un  `CardView`.

Comment: Encontre una alternativa:

TextView iv = new TextView(this);
 iv.setText("Letrasletras");
 iv.setTag("tag");

rl.addView(iv);

y despues...

iv_tag=(TextView)rl.findViewWithTag("tag");
iv_tag.setText("New");

respecto a : "Lo que no entiendo es por qué, si tú tienes ya un TextView en ese contexto ¿para qué quieres otro?"

Lo que pasa que el primer Textview esta dentro de una funcion, la cual se usa segun se demande(por ejemplo para hacer memes(texto en fotos)).

La proxima vez pondre el codigo tal y como lo tengo en el proyecto , mil disculpas. Gracias por tu tiempo =)

Comment: Creo que lo que intentas es algo como esto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3204852/android-add-a-textview-to-linear-layout-programmatically